# Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, MovieList>?' in type cast

Tags: flutter, firebase, dictionary, firebase-realtime-database

> Error:  Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, MovieList>?' in type cast

I am currently trying to read a data from a firebase realtime database, by using the readFavorite function described below. And then, i want to add the response to the Fav variable (the comment code in the read method).

Im still a newbie at flutter

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geekiga/models/movieList.dart';
import 'package:geekiga/providers/authService.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

class Favorite with ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, MovieList> _Fav = {};
  Map<String, MovieList> get Fav => _Fav;
  final firebase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;

  bool AddFav(String id, String uid, String title, String cover, String year,
      String desc, String url) {
    if (_Fav.containsKey(id)) {
      _Fav.remove(id);
      // deleteFromFavorite(uid, id);
      deleteFromFavoriteRTDB(uid, id);
      notifyListeners();

      return false;
    } else {
      _Fav.putIfAbsent(id, () => MovieList(id, title, year, cover, desc, url));
      notifyListeners();

      addtoFavoriteRTDB(
        id,
        uid,
        title,
        cover,
        year,
        desc,
        url,
      );

      return true;
    }
  }

  List<MovieList> get favorite_list {
    return [...favorite_list];
  }

  void notifyListeners() {}

  Future<void> addtoFavoriteRTDB(String id, String uid, String title,
      String cover, String year, String desc, String url) async {
    DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userfav/$uid/$id');

    await ref.set({
      "id": id,
      "uid": uid,
      "title": title,
      "cover": cover,
      "year": year,
      "desc": desc,
      "url": url,
    });
  }

  void deleteFromFavoriteRTDB(String uid, String id) {
    DatabaseReference ref =
        FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('userfav/$uid/$id');
    ref.remove();
  }

  Future<void> readFavorite(String uid) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse(
        'https://geekiga-mobile-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app/userfav/$uid.json');

    var hasilGetData = await http.get(url);
    // print(hasilGetData.body);

    var dataResponse = json.decode(hasilGetData.body) as Map<String, dynamic>?;

    print(dataResponse);
    Fav.clear();
    // dataResponse?.forEach(
    //   (key, value) {
    //     Fav.addAll(
    //       MovieList(
    //         id: value["id"],
    //         movie_title: value["title"],
    //         movie_year: value,
    //         movie_img: value,
    //         movie_desc: value,
    //         movie_url: value,
    //       )
    //       as Map<String, MovieList>
    //       ,
    //     );
    //   },
    // );
  }
}
```

But i keep getting error message Unhandled Exception: type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, MovieList>?' in type cast, in my watchlist page down below

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geekiga/pages/videoPlayer.dart';
import 'package:geekiga/providers/authService.dart';
import 'package:geekiga/providers/favorite.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class MoviePage extends StatelessWidget {
  String movie_id;
  String movie_title;
  String movie_year;
  String movie_img;
  String movie_desc;
  String movie_url;

  MoviePage(this.movie_id, this.movie_title, this.movie_year, this.movie_img,
      this.movie_desc, this.movie_url,
      {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // CollectionReference watchlist = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('watchlist');
    final firebase = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
    final favorite = Provider.of<Favorite>(context, listen: false);
    return Scaffold(
      // appBar: AppBar(
      //   backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      //   foregroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      //   elevation: 0,
      //   actions: <Widget>[],
      // ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Opacity(
            opacity: 0.6,
            child: Image.asset(
              movie_img,
              height: 280,
              width: double.infinity,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 25),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Icon(
                          Icons.arrow_back,
                          // color: Colors.white,
                          size: 30,
                          weight: 100,
                        ),
                      ),
                      // InkWell(
                      //   onTap: () {},
                      //   child: Icon(
                      //     Icons.favorite_border,
                      //     // color: Colors.white,
                      //     size: 35,
                      //   ),
                      // ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 60,
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(170, 0, 0, 0)
                                      .withOpacity(0.5),
                                  spreadRadius: 1,
                                  blurRadius: 8),
                            ]),
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          child: Image.asset(
                            movie_img,
                            height: 220,
                            width: 150,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      InkWell(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) =>
                                    VideoPlayerPage(movie_url)),
                          );
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 40, top: 40),
                          height: 80,
                          width: 80,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 137, 33),
                                  spreadRadius: 2,
                                  blurRadius: 8,
                                )
                              ]),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.play_arrow,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            size: 60,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 15),
                Center(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 90, vertical: 5),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Color(0xFFF292B37),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                          child: IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                (favorite.AddFav(
                                            movie_id,
                                            Provider.of<AuthService>(context,
                                                        listen: false)
                                                    .userId ??
                                                "No Name",
                                            movie_title,
                                            movie_img,
                                            movie_year,
                                            movie_desc,
                                            movie_url) ==
                                        true)
                                    ? ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                            content: Text(
                                                "Berhasil Ditambahkan ke dalam Watchlist"),
                                            duration:
                                                Duration(milliseconds: 500)))
                                    : ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                        content: Text(
                                            "Berhasil Dihapus dari Watchlist"),
                                        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                      ));
                              },
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.bookmark_add_rounded,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,
                              )),
                        ),
                        // Container(
                        //   height: 60,
                        //   width: 60,
                        //   padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        //       color: Color(0xFFF292B37),
                        //       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        //   child: IconButton(
                        //       onPressed: () {
                        //         favorite.RemoveFav(movie_id);
                        //         ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                        //             .showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                        //           content:
                        //               Text("Berhasil Dihapus dari Watchlist"),
                        //           duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        //         ));
                        //       },
                        //       icon: Icon(
                        //         Icons.bookmark_remove_rounded,
                        //         color: Colors.white,
                        //         size: 30,
                        //       )),
                        // ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15, horizontal: 10),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          movie_title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            // color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 15,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          movie_desc,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            // color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10),
              ],
            )),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If i change the cast to List, i can't append the list data to the Fav array (use the add)
How do i fix it??

Comment: try to print `hasilGetData.body` and  `json.decode(hasilGetData.body) as  List?`